# SSM send command to EC2 instance Failed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, instances, ssm

I'm trying to use boto3 to run ssh commands on EC2 instances.
I read this guide:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-remote-commands.html
and I did everything of what they wrote there but I keep get error message:

```
>>>import boto3
>>> ec2 = boto3.client('ssm')
>>> a = ec2.send_command(InstanceIds=['i-0d5e16f6'], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Comment='abcdabcd', Parameters={"commands":["ifconfig"]})
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 253, in _api_call
  return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 543, in _make_api_call
  raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
  botocore.errorfactory.InvalidInstanceId: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation:
```

if I'm trying to send command with awscli I get the same problem:

```
aws ssm send-command --instance-ids "i-0d5e16f6" --document-name "AWS-RunShellScript" --comment "IP config" --parameters commands=ifconfig --output text

An error occurred (InvalidInstanceId) when calling the SendCommand operation:
```

some one know how to solve it?

Comment: Is the instance in a different region? Make sure you have the correct AWS account and region configured with your SDK and/or CLI tool.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can happen when you don't have [SSM agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html) installed on the instance you're trying to access. For a list of instances where you can run SSM commands, run:

```
aws ssm describe-instance-information --output text
```

From there, you can grab an instance ID and then run the `send_command` command with that instance.

Answer (score 7):

As documented [here in AWS' troubleshooting guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_SendCommand.html) there are a range of possible causes for this error.

The accepted answer `aws ssm describe-instance-information` checks for instances which are both available, in a valid state and have the SSM agent installed, so that covers several of troubleshooting steps in one line (nice ;) ).

If you're using `boto3` the same can be achieved with:

```
ssm.client.describe_instance_information()
```

I'm not certain whether it checks permissions but presume so. If your instance_id is missing from the list, you can ensure correct permissions by following the step by step [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-access.html).

However, there is another cause (last but *definitely not least* as it's not obvious):

**Freshly created instances take a little while to show up in the `describe_instance_information` list**.

This is *even after waiting* for the instance to complete post-creation. So for example doing:

```
    # Key names are the same as the keyword arguments required by boto
    params = {
            'ImageId': image_id_to_use,
            'InstanceType': instance_type_to_launch,
            'MinCount': 1,
            'MaxCount': 1,
            'UserData': user_data_script,
            'SecurityGroups': ['your groups'],
            'KeyName': 'yourkeyname',
          }

    # Run the instance and wait for it to start
    reservation = ec2.client.run_instances(**params)
    instance = ec2.resource.Instance(reservation['Instances'][0]['InstanceId'])
    instance.wait_until_running()

    # Also wait status checks to complete
    waiter = ec2.client.get_waiter('instance_status_ok')
    waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[instance.id])

    # Apply the IAM roles required (this instance will need access to, e.g., S3)
    response = ec2.client.associate_iam_instance_profile(
        IamInstanceProfile={
            'Arn': 'your_arn',
            'Name': 'ApplicableRoleEGAdministratorAccess'
        },
        InstanceId=instance.id
    )

    print('Instance id just created:', instance.id)
    print('Instances in the SSM instances list right now:')
    print(ssm.client.describe_instance_information()['InstanceInformationList'])
```

Will highlight this problem (if present - it certainly was for me).

This *may* be due to the time taken to execute the UserData script (see [this SO post for a possibly-related discussion on waiting for user data to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312762/aws-autoscaling-starts-not-ready-instances-because-of-userdata-script)), but I can't tell (without more effort than I'm willing to take!) whether it's that, or just the time inherent in AWS updating its services database.

To solve this, I wrote a short waiter (with a timeout exception to handle other failure modes) that repeatedly called describe_instance_information() until the instance id showed up in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has an accepted answer but I think it is helpful to ad one small comment on the issue.

In my case I did not have the IAM role attached to the EC2 instance. And, interestingly, even after attaching the role, it was not working for me!

One trick that worked was restarting the SSM agent on the EC2 machine:

```bash
[ec2-user@ip-10-114-54-78 ~]$ sudo systemctl stop amazon-ssm-agent
[ec2-user@ip-10-114-54-78 ~]$ sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
```